# Display Batch output in TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, batch-file, process, command-line-arguments

I have tried to run the batch file from c# using the following code and i want to display the result in WPF textbox. Could you please guide me how to do this?

```
using System;

namespace Learn
{
    class cmdShell
    {
        [STAThread]  // Lets main know that multiple threads are involved.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc; // Declare New Process
            proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\listfiles.bat"); // run test.bat from command line.
            proc.WaitForExit(); // Waits for the process to end.
        }
    }
}
```

This batch file is to list the files from the folder. Once the batch is executed result should be displayed in the textbox. If the **batch file having more than one commands, then result of each commands should be displayed in textbox**.

Comment: The result are furring from a different file thus different process, you can access your application using Pipe (or WCF) you won't be able to fish out those results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issues with process hanging and getting output instantly as below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "test.bat";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
           proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
            proc.Start();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        }
    }


        void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                        {
                            txtprogress.Text = txtprogress.Text + "\n" + e.Data;
                            txtprogress.ScrollToEnd();
                        }));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to redirect the standard output stream:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "test.bat";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.Start();
            string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(output); // or do something else with the output
            proc.WaitForExit();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this working fine. but output is displayed once the execution completed, is there anything need to add for this?

Comment: The `StandardOutput` property of the `Process` class is a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamreader) instance. You don't need to wait for the execution to end. For example: if you use `proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine()` in a loop you can wait for the next line to be written and push it to your textbox immediately. See the documentation for more information.